# How to make a dropdown box(select element) to accept text search in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down(select element) box. What I want is to be able to search the options in the same element by typing. I have tried the datalist in html5, but in that the typed value will be accepted as input if there is no value in options. I want the option to be chosen from the option list, but should be able to find it by typing a  text.

```
 <select name="xyz">
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
<option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```

here if I type "A" to search the option a should be chosen. If I type "X" to search it should not be accepted as an input.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<datalist>`

```
<input type=text list=browsers>
<datalist id=browsers>
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="InternetExplorer">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```